# jQuery prev/next slider --> how to disable prev/next on first/last slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/t2zwo0fr/2/

I want to to is to disable next/previous buttons in the following cases:

1. disable previous button when first slide is present within border;
2. disable next button when animation reached last slide;

   **In other words:**

   1. on the first slide preset inside section I want to prevent the slider from going any further right and...
   2. on the last slide present inside section I want to prevent the
      slider from going any further left;

HTML:

```
 <a href="" class="prev">prev</a>
 <a href="" class="next">next</a>
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
        West African lion population is particularly endangered.
    </li>
    <li>
        West African lion population is particularly endangered.
    </li>
      <li>
        West African lion population is particularly endangered.
    </li>  
  </ul>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
  var szer1slidu = $('ul li').width();
  var wys1slidu = $('ul li').height();
  var slideCount = $('ul li').length;
  var calosc = slideCount * szer1slidu;
  var active = false;

    $('section').css({
    width: szer1slidu,
    height: wys1slidu
  });

    $('ul').css ({
    width: calosc
  });

    $('.next').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
           if (active) {
               return;
             }
          active = true;
        $('ul').animate({'left': $('ul').position().left-szer1slidu},                   2000, function() { { active = false; }
        });   
  });


    $('.prev').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          if (active) {
                return;
            }
        active = true;
        $('ul').stop().animate({
          'left': $('ul').position().left+szer1slidu}, 2000, function() {
        { active = false; }
        });
            });
```

Comment: Could increment/decrement a counter on each click and compare to slideCount  or zero to hide/show appropriate buttons

Comment: ...it might work

Comment: Is a common approach...will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an index:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
```

next: `if slideIndex < slideCount - 1` then `next` and `slideIndex++`.
prev: `if slideIndex > 0` then `prev` and `slideIndex--`.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/t2zwo0fr/8/

Comment: OP already has variable `slideCount` that has the `length`. No need to duplicate code

Comment: glegoux Thank you for the answer . I can't vote yet dont have enough reputatnion points

Answer (score 0):

There are similar or even better solutions than mine. But what I suggest and did is to add a `data-slide` attribute to `<ul>` which hold the current slide. And I started this from 1.

Check JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/junaidkbr/1zt3qLb5/4/